# Windows: Get message sent to a parent window?

Tags: windows

Using a `EM_SETEVENTMASK` message can set which notifications a rich edit control sends to its parent window. How can I intercept/be notified of these messages?

Ideally, I'd have a callback that I could register with certain notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like any traditional approach will do:

- Instance subclassing (replace
  parent's window procedure with your
  own and check the messages coming
  from the control of interest). Refer
  to MSDN's CallWindowProc.
- Hooking.
  Refer to MSDN's SetWindowsHookEx.